# How can I copy a specific page design from an existing book?

Tags: pagestyle

I'm learning `LaTeX` and I want to make this layout for my page, but it is difficult for me to draw this in `LaTeX`.
Can someone please help me?
[image: Example page from the book to be copied]

Comment: Hi user, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show the full page and let us know, if this is for a report, a book, a letter? Only the stating page of a chapter? Is the D a logo that is the same all the time, or shall it change? Does Cap. II means chapter II? Just some more context would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi Toby! I updated the image. I want make this separation with this horizontal and vertical line, put images on the right column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am running out of time, but here is a beginning and others are invited to work on it:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ROMA AETERNA}
\section{Palatium et Capitolium}
Urbs Roma in ripa Tiberis fluminis sita est viginti milia passuum a mari. Hoc loco flumen facile transitur, et colles propinqui bene muniri possunt.\marginpar{complecti: cingere}
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{Capitolinus-a-um < Capitolium}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw (current page marginpar area.south west) -- (current page marginpar area.north west);
\draw (current page marginpar area.north east) -- (current page text area.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Look further into changing the chapter title style, e.g. with `titlesec` and have a look how to load graphics with `\includegraphics`. For the header the `fancyhdr` package might be of interest for you, too.

Comment: Thank you very much Tobi! I will work on this.